# Laravel 5.1 Unable to Run Test on User Password Mutator

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I have a password mutator:

```
/**
 * Mutator for setting the encryption on the user password.
 *
 * @param $password
 */
public function getPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes[ 'password' ] = bcrypt($password);
}
```

That I'm trying to test:

```
/**
 * A basic check of password mutator.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testCheckPasswordEncryptionUserAttribute()
{
    $userFactory = factory('Project\User')->create([
        'password' => 'test'
    ]);

    $user = User::first();

    $this->assertEquals(bcrypt('test'), $user->password);
}
```

That when the test runs I get this error:

```
1) UserTest::testCheckPasswordEncryptionUserAttribute
Failed asserting that null matches expected '$2y$10$iS278efxpv3Pi6rfu4/1eOoVkn4EYN1mFF98scSf2m2WUhrH2kVW6'.
```

After the test failed I attempted to dd() the password property, but that also failed.  My first thought was this might be a mass assignment issue (having just read about that), but password is in $fillable (which makes sense that it would be there), then I noticed $hidden in the User class as well, but after reading about that in the docs, and also removing the password index for $hidden it still produces a null when you try to access the password property.

How would you unit test this mutator, or what have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to change "get" to "set" in your method name.

Methods starting with "get" are accessors. These are not supposed to change the field / attribute value but return a "mutated" value (yours returns nothing that's why you get `null`).

Methods starting with "set" are designed to change the value of the field (mutators) and this seems to be exactly what you need.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

```
/**
 * Mutator for setting the encryption on the user password.
 *
 * @param $password
 */
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
```

You can make "password" hidden, because this won't affect your test.

P.S. If I'm not wrong, `factory('...')->create()` returns an instance of a newly created model (`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`), so you don't have to do `User::first()`:

```
/**
 * A basic check of password mutator.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testCheckPasswordEncryptionUserAttribute()
{
    $user = factory('Project\User')->create(['password' => 'test']);

    $this->assertTrue(Hash::check('test', $user->password));
}
```

Comment: Hi, it makes sense not to make the password fillable, but I wonder why they set it as fillable on a clean install.  Do you just use the query builder to update the password then if you can't mass assign it using create.  The test runs now, but fails due to a mismatch in the values, which I don't understand how that could occur as I'm setting the password and the mutator is now working properly using your fix, but definitely never the same value.

Comment: Hi, I changed this up to use password_hash and password_verify, now compares the hashes properly and passes phpunit.  Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome. No idea why it's fillable by deafult. Are you sure? It can be hidden but very unlikely to be fillable.

I think you had problems comparing passwords because bcrypt produces different results even when you hash the same value.

You can also use Laravel's Hash facade to comare passwords (see edited test code in the answer):
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing